# How can the smart contract auto execute the function in the private chain?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, contract-design, scheduling

I know currently, we can use the Ethereum Alarm Clock and Aion scheduling system to execute the function automatically, but according to what I know, it only can work in Main Net and Test Net(Rposten). My question is, Is that possible to work in the private chain by using one of these two solutions(EAC or Aion). If both ways can't work in a private chain, Are there any solution to execute the function automatically in the private chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Aion, you have the smart contract available on the [Aion's GitHub page](https://github.com/ETH-Pantheon/Aion), so you can just deploy it in your private network. However, you will need to develop the script that executes the transactions as this has not been made available in the Aion page. But this basically read the logs of the `ScheduleCallEvent`, the parameters of this event are all you need for your script to be able to call the `executeCall` function.

This is a big difference between `EAC` and `Aion`. EAC saves a lot of data in the network. All this causes a huge difference in gas consumption for scheduling transactions, `EAC` uses about 500K gas for a single transaction, Aion uses only about 80K.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so, if I deploy in the private chain, can I avoid this line of code? [aion = Aion(0xFcFB45679539667f7ed55FA59A15c8Cad73d9a4E);]  because the address is use in MainNet and Ropsten.

Comment: You will change that by the address or your deployed Aion contract. Notice that this line is in the examples of how to use Aion, not in the main Aion contract.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I misunderstand or not, the example in Aion's GitHub page the contract Aion and contract MyContract is a different smart contract, and in my case, after I deploy the contract Aion then get the address, and put the address at here [aion = Aion(here);](MyContract),am I correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Just right a `cron job` that will execute a script that will `send transaction` to the network and invokes the `function`. I think the `EAC` and `Aion` are doing the same thing.

Comment: sorry, are there any tutorial for smart contract using cron job?

Comment: No, There are for cron jobs though